# Can I access system/environment variables from LaTeX? For instance, $HOME

Tags: macros, programming, environment-variables

For instance, I want to include a figure: `~/figures/figure.pdf`. On my Linux box, this is `/home/me/figures/figure.pdf`, but on OS X it is `/Users/me/figures/figure.pdf`. I'd like it if there is an environment variable like `$HOME` so that the latex file can compile on both machines `\includegraphics{$HOME/figures/figure.pdf}`. (Of course it wouldn't use the `$` sign).

I just found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/accessing-environment-variables-within-a-document), but Is write18 the most native way? And, in the given example, the assignment wouldn't actually define the variable in LaTex. I tried

```
\immediate\write18{echo "\newcommand{\HOME}{$HOME}" > var.tex}
```

But gives me this error:

```
! Argument of \@gobble has an extra }.
```

So now I am at a loss.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/accessing-environment-variables-within-a-document

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have a recent TeX Live (2010 or later) or MiKTeX (v. 2.9), then the following works (and does not need the `-shell-escape` command line option):

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}

\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}
```

If you only say `\getenv{VAR}` then the value of the variable is printed instead of being stored in a control sequence.

Not only `HOME` can be used, but any environment variable and also the "pseudovariables" defined in the TeX `kpathsea` system such as `TEXMF` or `TEXINPUTS`.

Note that this works *only* with `pdflatex`. With other engines or older distributions, shell escape is needed. Of course LuaTeX has its methods for interacting with the system.

---

A version that works with all *recent* engines is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{catchfile}
  \newcommand\getenv[2][]{%
    \immediate\write18{kpsewhich --var-value #2 > \jobname.tmp}%
    \CatchFileDef{\temp}{\jobname.tmp}{\endlinechar=-1}%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \newcommand\getenv[2][]{%
      \edef\temp{\directlua{tex.sprint(
        kpse.var_value("\luatexluaescapestring{#2}") or "" ) }}%
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
  \else
    \usepackage{catchfile}
    \newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
      \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1}%
      \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
  \fi
\fi

\begin{document}
\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}\show\HOME
\end{document}
```

In the case of `xetex` an auxiliary file `\jobname.tmp` is written and `-shell-escape` is necessary.

Note: the LuaTeX method has been suggested by Patrick Gundlach. If the variable is unset or not known to `kpathsea`, the empty string will result.

---

UPDATE 2019

With recent and up-to-date TeX distributions, the following works with every engine (except, of course, Knuth TeX): `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`, `platex` and `uplatex`. Unrestricted shell escape is not necessary.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}\show\HOME

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to use `\getenv[VAR]{envvar}` in a situation where `envvar` may not have been defined.    I've been trying unsuccessfully to condition on the output of `\getenv` in this case.   Is it possible to modify the command so that it returns something like UNDEFINED if there environment variable hasn't been defined?

Comment: @LeoSimon Add before the `\if\relax` lines, the line `\ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi` Or do a test for emptyness when the macro is used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't get it to work.    Here's an MWE, although I don't know how to put code into a comment      `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \ifx\temp\empty\def\temp{UNDEFINED}\fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
\begin{document}
The getenv command should return UNDEFINED but returns
\getenv{NOT_DEFINED}
\end{document}`
In this example `\getenv{NOT_DEFINED}` returns empty

Comment: @LeoSimon If you have a followup question, please ask one

Comment: This used to work pretty well, but a recent change to `kpsewhich` broke it unfortunately: When called with `--var-value`, it doesn't print the environment variable's content verbatim, but does brace expansion on the value. Unfortunately, even that is buggy, so that it expands a comma even outside of curly braces:


`$ CHAMAELEOGEOMETRY='XX=yy,z=4' kpsewhich --var-value CHAMAELEOGEOMETRY
XX=yy:z=4`


I used to suppl comma-separated values here (for setting a page geometry from outside), but since the comma gets converted to a colon, that doesn't any longer work. A `kpsewhich` bug?

Comment: One containing a comma, which gets "expanded" to a colon, thus breaking the actual variable content.

Comment: @Jan-BenedictGlaw What system are you on? On my system I get `XX=yy,z=4` as output from the command line you show.

Comment: Then it was changed again.....

I also found another workaround: Instead of using `kpsewhich`, a simple `echo` will do as well.

Comment: @Jan-BenedictGlaw The difference is that `echo` requires shell-escape, whereas `kpsewhich` doesn't.

Comment: The 'recent updates' in your last answer are very recent indeed. 2019-09-20?

Comment: @steveo'america I guess so. `;-)`

Comment: I'm using the version in the first snippet here. I have an issue, if I type `\getenv{HOME}.` (with a dot after the end), in the output file a blank space is added between the content of `HOME` and `.`. Can somebody help?

Comment: @GilbertoT. I’ll have a look in s few days.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the support.

Comment: @GilbertoT. `\endlinechar=-1` was missing.

Comment: @egreg You're totally right. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 15):

@egreg has already answered your question so I thought I'd not answer it. That is suggest not relying on environment variables for this. If the latex file just goes `\includegraphics{figures/figure.pdf}`

then if `$HOME/figures//` is in TEXINPUTS environment variable or `texmf.cnf` configuration setting then the file will be found without LaTeX explicitly needing to access the machine-specific information. This keeps machine specific information and directory structure in the kpathsearch system which is optimised to deal with that rather than the macro layer which tries as far as possible to avoid such issues.

Also for the specific case of home directory you can (on web2c systems on at least linux and windows/cygwin, but I assume the others too)  use `\string~/figures/figure.pdf` as kpathsea understands `~` as the home directory (but you have to pass it a literal `~` not the normal active definition for a non-breakable space, hence the `\string`.

Answer (score 3):

The updated answer from @egreg for new versions did not work for me however this did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
{
  \sys_get_shell:nnN{ kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }{}#1
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}
\HOME

\end{document}
```

I do not know if this is the expected behaviour but it works for me and based on the documentation for `\sys_get_shell:nnN` it seems to be the intended behaviour.

Comment: Not sure why you say “it doesn't work”, because your macro just does the same as mine, with the difference that you can't just say `\getenv{FOO}` to simply print the value. Oh, and you'll get some weird error if you don't specify the optional argument.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice you specified the second parameter as optional. Your version leads to an error during compilation. Upon further inspection I got your version working by removing the `\show`

Comment: `\show` uses the error message mechanism. I used it just to print *on the terminal* the value assigned to `\HOME`.

Comment: Note that \usepackage{xstring} can be used to strip the extra space in the \HOME token with \StrGobbleRight{\HOME}{1}[\strippedHOME]