# How to include a second file only if environment variable is set?

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, environment-variables

I have a LaTeX document which exists in two versions, a short version and the long version. The long version has an additional chapter inserted in the middle of the document. What I want to do, is if I have an environment variable set, include the additional file at the relevant point. So I am doing this (in pdflatex):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
\getenv[\INCLUDE]{INCLUDE}
\begin{document}
First paragraph of first file.

Value of the INCLUDE envvar is as follows: \INCLUDE

\ifstrequal{\INCLUDE}{yes}{\input{file2}}{}

Last paragraph of first file.
\end{document}
```

I know it can read the environment variable correctly, so I can see the problem is with the conditional, but not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. When I run this with INCLUDE=yes, the value yes is printed, but file2's contents does not appear.

(This is like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build), but that question does not address environment variables. I got my environment variable code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62032/54565), but since I can print the environment variable correctly, I don't think that is the problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Improved version

There are two basically two problems:

1. `\ifstrequal` does not expand its arguments
2. The content of the environment variable has a trailing whitespace character 
   at the end, which means `yes` will become `yes' '`, so that the test fails. I could not figure out the reason up to now.

By usage of the `xstring` package command `\StrGobbleRight` and `\ifdefstring` from `etoolbox` package, it is possible to cope around, hopefully, that it is just one character at the end to be deleted. See the effect as diagnostics in the top of the output document, when `\temp` and `\newtemp` macros output -- if the whitespace is removed, the content of the environment variable and the following text should be glued together.

I redefined the `getenv` command to `\newgetenv` and used an expanded `\edef\temp` to make the `\ifdefstring` command work with the literal `yes` value.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xstring}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%

\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\let#1\temp\fi}
%\getenv[\INCLUDE]{\string INCLUDE}

\def\newtemp{}%
\newcommand{\newgetenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{}%
  \StrGobbleRight{\temp}{1}[\newtemp]%  Delete the trailing whitespace character
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\edef#1{\newtemp}\fi%
}%


\begin{document}
\newgetenv[\INCLUDE]{INCLUDE}%
%%% Diagnostics:
\temp%
Some Text% 

\newtemp% 
Some Text%

First paragraph of first file.

Value of the INCLUDE envvar is as follows: \INCLUDE

\ifdefstring{\INCLUDE}{yes}{\input{file2}}{Nothing to do in here}

Last paragraph of first file.

\end{document}
```

---

The file `file2.tex` just contains the line

```
\textbf{Hello World}
```

[image]

**Another version (Thanks to the hint made by H. Oberdiek)**

The trailing whitespace(`\endlinechar`) can be omitted by using `\endlinechar=-1\relax` as 3rd argument to `\CatchFileEdef` command. This simplifies the handling of the environment variable macro and the usage of `xstring` package can be dropped.

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{catchfile}%


\newcommand{\newgetenv}[2][]{%
 \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1\relax}%
 \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\edef#1{\temp}\fi%
}%


\begin{document}
\newgetenv[\INCLUDE]{INCLUDE}%

First paragraph of first file.

Value of the INCLUDE envvar is as follows: \INCLUDE

\ifdefstring{\INCLUDE}{yes}{\input{file2}}{Nothing to do in here}

Last paragraph of first file.

\end{document}
```

I did not update the screenshot, nothing essential has changed in the output.

Comment: If it works this way is just by chance; better doing it in the proper way: `\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\INCLUDE}{yes}{...}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I have already suspected, that it would not be sufficient. I will update

Comment: The space at the end of the command result can be avoided by using `\endlinechar=-1\relax` in the third argument of `\CatchFileEdef`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I will update later on, but thanks for that information

Comment: yes, this works and is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way that doesn't require shell escape. Let's say your file is called `file1.tex`. Then you can organize it as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\providecommand{\INCLUDE}[1]{}

\begin{document}
First paragraph of first file.

\INCLUDE{file2}

Last paragraph of first file.
\end{document}
```

If you call the LaTeX run by

```
pdflatex "$INCLUDE\input{file1}"
```

then, if you don't set `INCLUDE` in the environment the result would be that `\INCLUDE` has no effect. On the other hand, setting

```
export INCLUDE='\let\INCLUDE\input'
```

the same command line as before will input `file2`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the book class with chapters. Then it is easy with `\includeonly`

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{file2,file3}% controlls what will be included
\begin{document}
First paragraph of first file.

\include{file2}
\include{file3}

Last paragraph of first file.
\end{document}
```

You can also use an external file `include.cfg` which has only the `\includeonly{...}` line:

```
\documentclass{book}
\InputIfFileExists{include.cfg}% controlls what will be included
\begin{document}
```

Comment: I think this paginates the short version as if all the unincluded files were there. That may or may not suit the OP.