# Possible to compile a tex file with command line arguments passed to the tex file?

Tags: pdftex

Is it possible to compile a tex file with command line arguments passed to the tex file? For example, a tex file `merge.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to use this like a shell command, where I can specify any two pdf files to replace `1.pdf` and `2.pdf` at each compilation of the tex file, something like `pdflatex merge.tex first.pdf second.pdf`.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a shell script with 2 arguments. You call this script and pass two pdf files and the script will take each one and copy them to the same source pdf file, for example, `first.pdf` and `second.pdf`. Then you include always those pdf files in your tex file and finally the script runs `pdflatex merge.tex`.

Comment: You could use a shell environment variable which is evaluated during compilation, see a (different example) here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184923/how-to-include-a-second-file-only-if-environment-variable-is-set

Answer (score 8):

merge.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{\filea.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{\fileb.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Then a command line of

```
pdflatex '\def\filea{myfile1}\def\fileb{myfile2}\input merge'
```

Should do as you ask.

Depending on which system commandline you use, you may need different quote `'` or to double the `\` to `\\`

Comment: What a simple command?! Nice!

Comment: thanks. what if `merge.tex` isn't stored in the current directory?

Comment: @Tim well if it's somewhere where `pdflatex merge` works, that will work, or you can put the full path after the `\input` just as you can (but probably shouldn't) do `pdflatex a/b/c/merge`

Comment: put the pathname of `merge.tex` into `$PATH` of Ubuntu doesnt' work, does it?

Comment: @Tim `merge.tex` isn't a command so PATH isn't relevant it can be in any directory in the tex input path, just as latex packages, TEXINPUTS, specified as an environment variable , or more normally in the  texmf.cnf file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, if `myfile1` is passed to a script and stored in variable `$myfile`, how to call `pdflatex`? I guess that `\def\filea{$myfile1}` will not work, will?

Comment: @Sigur it depends on your shell, but if you use `"` rather than `'` then the shell should expand `$myfile` but you may need `\\ ` and `\{` for `\ ` and `{`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, let me try. Thanks. By the way, I use `bash`.