# ifdefstring + lstinline = need to escape characters

Tags: listings, etoolbox

I'm using `\ifdefstring` as part of a conditional definition which depends on an environment variable, as indicated [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home).

It works mostly fine, except that inside the blocks defined by `\ifdefstring`, if I have a `\lstinline` containing backslashes, I need to escape them, otherwise it won't work.

I'd like to be able to add `\ifdefstring` blocks without having to escape/unescape what's inside, especially because the error message is not very clear: missing backslashes lead to cryptic error messages at the end of the block. Is there a way to do so?

Here's an MVE, where in each case (both inside and outside the `\ifdefstring`) a single backslash must be printed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% catchfile block copied from other question
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1\relax}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\edef#1{\temp}\fi}
\getenv[\VAR]{VAR}%

\begin{document}
\ifdefstring{\VAR}{yes}{
  \lstinline|\\must_be_escaped_yes|
}{
  \lstinline|\\must_be_escaped_not_yes|
}

\lstinline|\must_not_be_escaped|

\end{document}
```

The output (here, with `VAR != yes`) is:

[image: MVE for ifdefstring with lstinline inside]

But to make it parsable, I had to manually add the extra `\` inside the `\lstinline` parts inside the `\ifdefstring` blocks, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Can you show examples of how and why `VAR` should be somehow escaped and what you mean by that?

Comment: I tried to clarify the example. I do not want to escape `VAR`, I would like to have LaTeX code that is the same whether it is inside an `\ifdefstring` block or not.

Comment: You can't: `\lstinline` is a verbatim like command; it has features that allow putting it in the argument to a command, but you need some escapes, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\lstinline` is a bit different from other verbatim commands, so it *can* go in the argument to another command, but with limitations.

You can define an `\else`–`\fi` form of `\ifdefstring` so you can use the unescaped version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% catchfile block copied from other question
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand{\getenv}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileEdef{\temp}{"|kpsewhich --var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1\relax}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\temp\else\edef#1{\temp}\fi}

\newcommand{\defstring}[2]{%
  TT\fi
  \ifdefstring{#1}{#2}{\iftrue}{\iffalse}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\getenv[\VAR]{VAR}

\begin{document}
\if\defstring{\VAR}{yes}
  \lstinline|\must_be_escaped_yes|
\else
  \lstinline|\must_be_escaped_not_yes|
\fi

\lstinline|\must_not_be_escaped|

\end{document}
```

### Output with `VAR` unset

[image]

### Output with `VAR` set to `yes`

[image]