# Escape return value from \sys_get_shell

Tags: verbatim, expl3, latex3, shell-escape, environment-variables

I stumbled upon [this question regarding accessing environment variables from latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home) and have problems properly escaping variables containing special tex symbols (e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`)

My closest attempt can be found below but it still replaces the underscore with a weird dot:

[image: environment variable with superscript dot instead of underscore]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
{
  \sys_get_shell:nnN{ kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }{}#1
}


\begin{document}

\getenv[\LANG]{LANG}

\tl_to_str:N\LANG

\end{document}
```

Furthermore this also does not correctly handle other special symbols like `@`

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. This is a duplicate. Your definition is wrong, as I explained in a comment to your answer in the linked thread. What do you mean by the last paragraph?

Comment: I tried defining `AB='@'` in the shell and then `\getenv[\AB]{AB}\AB` prints the expected `@`.

Comment: Yes without the `\show` your definition worked and adding fontspec whilst using lualatex resolved the weird dot problem. I am so accustomed to lualatex that I forgot to add it whilst experimenting with the code. Thank you