# Switch based on whether or not an environment variable is set

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse, shell-escape

**TLDR**: Problem: `kpsewhich` outputs `\par` for unset environment variables and I do not know how to strip it.

I was inspired from the question [Can I access system/environment variables from LaTeX? For instance, $HOME](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home) after finding out that `kpsewhich` works without `--shell-escape` and am trying to create a switch based on whether or not a given environment variable is set. Then I can check if e.g. `DARK` is set and swap text and background color.

However the problem emerged that even for unset environment variables `kpsewhich` apparently outputs a newline which leads to the captured output not being empty. I already tried to strip it using `\tl_trim_spaces:N` (as is already the case in the linked answer) but to no avail.

Is it somehow possible to either (a) instruct `kpsewhich` not to print a newline for unset environment variables, (b) read the return code from `sys_get_shell:nnN` as `kpsewhich` fails with a non-zero exit code if the variable is not set or (c) strip the resulting `\par` from the variable?

**Credit goes to @Phelype Oleinik, check out his anwer for an explanation and also check out @egreg's answer for a solution without changing `\endlinechar`**

I could now implement what I wanted using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifenvset}{m m}
{
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #1 }
    { \int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar:D { -1 } }
    \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NTF { \l_tmpa_tl } {} { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ifenvset{DARK}{
  \pagecolor{black!90}
  \color{white!90}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\verb|lualatex darkmode.tex|\\
\verb|env DARK=1 lualatex darkmode.tex|\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: kpsewhich does not generate `\par` (you can run it on the commandline, it is generated by tex from the the implicit end-of file as you input the result, it's probably adjustable but it would help people test answers if you provided a test document

Comment: see egreg's `\endlinechar=-1` comment under his question so you ignore the eol

Comment: Yes I always try to add a MWE though this time it did not seem too useful as I just copied the LaTeX3 update from the linked answer and played around with `\tl_if_blank`, `\tl_to_str` and `\tl_count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a shell command, TeX sees it as if you had written the output of the command to a temporary (pseudo) file, and then read that file in. While reading that file, the usual rules apply: a line end is turned into a space, and an empty line is turned into a `\par` token.  When the output of the command is empty, it is as if the file had an empty line, and that is turned into a `\par`.  The usual trick is to set the `\endlinechar` parameter to `-1`, so that TeX doesn't insert anything at the end of a line, neither a `\par` token.

The second argument in `\sys_get_shell:nnN` is the `<setup>`, in which you can change these types of parameters before the command is executed and the pseudo file is read in, so you can do:

```latex
\sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }
  { \int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar:D { -1 } }
  \l_septatrix_env_tl
```

Putting that in egreg's `\getenv` code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_septatrix_env_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \getenv { o m }
  {
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 }
      { \int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar:D { -1 } }
      \l_septatrix_env_tl
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \tl_use:N \l_septatrix_env_tl }
      { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_septatrix_env_tl }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}\show\HOME

\getenv[\HOMER]{HOMER}\show\HOMER

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\int_set:Nn \tex_endlinechar` definitely seems to be more latex3 like compared to `\endlinechar` though I have been unable to find where this is documented. Are these internal variables just undocumented (`\endlinechar` is actually mentioned a few times in interface3)?
Nice to see you use my username as a scope name :D

Comment: Okay I just found the section. They are apparently undocumented on purpose as these primitives should not be used outside of kernel-level code which makes this solution a bit less clean but it work nevertheless

Comment: @Septatrix `\endlinechar` and `\tex_endlinechar:D` are two names for the same internal parameter: if you change one, the other will change as well. `\tex_endlinechar:D` is not documented because primitives (with signature `:D`) should not be used (the `:D` stands for “do not use”, even though it looks so happy :-). However we don't have an interface for `\endlinechar` yet, so we have to break the rules a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can define `\ifenvsetTF` (this is a better name, in my opinion} by

```latex
\tl_const:Nn \c_getenv_par_tl { \par }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifenvsetTF}{mmm}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \c_getenv_par_tl { #3 } { #2 }
 }
```

Full example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_getenv_par_tl { \par }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifenvsetTF}{mmm}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \c_getenv_par_tl { #3 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getenv{LC_CTYPE}

\ifenvsetTF{LC_CTYPE}{SET}{UNSET}

\ifenvsetTF{BOZO}{SET}{UNSET}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, note that variables set to empty value will trigger “unset” anyway (with this method and also with the `\endlinechar` method).

How to define an `expl3` conditional?

```latex
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \septatrix_if_setenv:n {T,F,TF}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \c_getenv_par_tl
   { \prg_return_false: }
   { \prg_return_true: }
 }
```

Full code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_getenv_par_tl { \par }
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \septatrix_if_setenv:n {T,F,TF}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #1 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_tl \c_getenv_par_tl
   { \prg_return_false: }
   { \prg_return_true: }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ifenvsetTF}{mmm}
 {
  \septatrix_if_setenv:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getenv{LC_CTYPE}

\ifenvsetTF{LC_CTYPE}{SET}{UNSET}

\ifenvsetTF{BOZO}{SET}{UNSET}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This methods seems a bit more clean without changing the `\endlinechar` (catcode?). Actually I am trying to figure out how to use `\prg_new_conditional` right now to get the complete set automatically :D

Comment: @Septatrix I added the code

Comment: Wow thanks, that looks very clean - I am starting to fall in love with latex3. Is the protected necessary or just a precaution?

Comment: @Septatrix It’s necessary, because the definition uses assignments.