# Pass a variable from makefile to latex code

Tags: macros, conditionals, latexmk, variable

I wrote a simple makefile to compile my latex code.

I have some variables in that makefile and I want to pass them to the latex code, but I don't know how to do that.

### Example 1:

in makefile:

```
# set Type to A or B
Type = B
```

in latex code:

```
\ifdefined\B
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Some LaTeX Code%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\else
\ifdefined\A
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Some LaTeX Code%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fi
\fi
```

### Example 2:

in makefile:

```
Version = J
```

in LaTeX code:

```
Some random text \Version
```

Here is the line in the makefile that I use for compilation:

```
latexmk -lualatex -output-directory=$(OUTDIR) --jobname=$(REPORT_PDF) $(REPORT)
```

Any help?

Comment: See also [macros - Can I access system/environment variables from LaTeX? For instance, $HOME - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62010/can-i-access-system-environment-variables-from-latex-for-instance-home)

Comment: (I would not use the (key-)word "Type" as the name of a variable). If all else fails: Maybe in the makefile, when calling LaTeX, you can specify the jobname option depending on the value of the variable "Type". E.g. for compiling test.tex as `typeAtest` or `typeBtest`.Then it can be checked whether the expansion of `\jobname` begins with "typeA" or "typeB". (With older latexmk-releases you may need `-latexoption="-jobname=..."`.) Since in TeX the names of the output files (.pdf/.log/.aux) also depend on the jobname, the makefile should rename the output files as desired when LaTeX is finished.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using luatex you can easily access the environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\directlua{tex.write(os.getenv("FOO"))}

\end{document}
```

will print 7 given

```
 FOO=7 lualatex file
```

so you can then test using Lua or TeX condtional code/

Comment: to pass the make variable to the environment either add it to the shell command as here or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843106/how-to-set-child-process-environment-variable-in-makefile

Comment: Nice solution, one caveat is that if the environment variable changes, `latexmk` will (I believe) not notice and so if that is the only change, it will not recompile even though the expected output would be different.

Comment: @VincentBeffara I guess you have a `make clean`  target that would wake latexmk up :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can always, in your Makefile, create an auxiliary file that LaTeX will read: namely, in the Makefile,

```
echo "\\def\\foo{$WHATEVER}" > foo.inc
```

and in your `.tex` file, just `\input{foo.inc}`.

Alternative option, you can do something a bit less brittle using the `catchfile` package that sets a LaTeX macro to the contents of a file: namely, in the Makefile,

```
echo $WHATEVER > foo.var
```

and in your `.tex` file,

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\foo}{}{foo.var}
```

(or, use `\file_get:nnN` if you prefer).

In both cases, `latexmk` will notice the changes to these auxiliary files and trigger recompilation when they change.