# is it possible to make setmainfont read environment variable to specify the font path in one place

Tags: fonts

I am using this command in latex to specify the font path:

```
\setmainfont[Color=primary, Path = fonts/source-han-serif/,BoldItalicFont=SourceHanSerifSC-Bold,BoldFont=SourceHanSerifSC-Bold,ItalicFont=SourceHanSerifSC-Bold]{SourceHanSerifSC-Regular}
```

now I have a issue that, I have many cls files that contains the font path, if I want to change the file path, I have to open each cls file and edit one by one. is it possible to make setmainfont to read the environment that I can specify the font path in one place? my possible operation system is Ubuntu and macOS.

Comment: Why don't you install the fonts in one of the default font paths?

Comment: If you don't know the paths searched for fonts, ask kpathsea, e.g. `kpsewhich -progname=lualatex -show-path=.otf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use my code at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62032/4427

Here I use a variant of a previous answer to your question about `HOME`, just by way of example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getenv}{om}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich ~ --var-value ~ #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\getenv[\HOME]{HOME}

\getenv[\TEST]{TEST}

\newfontface{\fell}{IMFePIit29C}[
  Path=\HOME/provaccia/conf-1.7b/fell/,
  Extension=.otf,
]

\begin{document}

\texttt{TEST is \TEST}

\texttt{TEST is \getenv{TEST}}

{\fell Hello}

\end{document}
```

I run this on `bash` as

```bash
TEST=foo xelatex dolphin
```

and the output is

[image]

Of course you're responsible for correctly defining and exporting the environment variable you need on each system.