# \if(username == foo) ... \else .. \fi?

Tags: conditionals, environment-variables

I think the pseudo code in the title says it all: How can TeX (or LaTeX) find out the $USER who is running `pdflatex`?

I'm collaborating want the output to look very slightly different when I run `latex` as opposed to when my collaborator does.

Comment: I don't think you can access envvars from LaTeX. If a regular conditional, or variable set in your .tex won't do, perhaps a custom Makefile? There was a relatex question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208161/to-get-the-current-user-in-latex

Comment: You might want to start by looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1728/accessing-environment-variables-within-a-document, which covers accessing system environment variables

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @ Joseph: Indeed, I saw that a bit later, but wondered if it really has to be "so complicated", i.e., need such tricky "contortions" ;-)   and so kept my question, hoping for a "nicer" answer.

Comment: While the answers (including mine) have looked at interesting ways of getting the environment variables, for the use case described I would not do that. The shared document can just use `\usepackage{local}` and you can have non-shared `local.sty` in each of your `~/texmf/tex/latex/misc/local.sty` and those files can do whatever you like in each case. No need for shell-escape or windows/unix difference worries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method that should work on all operating system (but is basically the same as David's) and needs also `-shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

% #1 = control sequence to define
% #2 = variable to get the value of
\newcommand{\getvar}[2]{%
  \CatchFileEdef#1{"|kpsewhich -var-value #2"}{\endlinechar=-1 }%
}

\def\me{enrico}
\getvar{\usrtest}{USER}

\begin{document}

\ifx\me\usrtest ME \else IMPOSTER\fi

\end{document}
```

With `kpsewhich` we can avoid quotes and dollars or `%`; the program should work the same on TeX Live and on MiKTeX. Of course the name of the variable to set might be different on the various operating systems: it's `USER` on Unix ones and `USERNAME` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, Enrico, (and David !).  Do I understand correctly that your solution would *not* need  '--shell-escape'?   {{and an aside: I'd wish something like this \getvar{} should be part of a standard LaTeX package...}}

Comment: @MartinMächler No, this needs `--shell-escape` as well

Answer (score 10):

My humble attempt with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{luacode}
-- get the username variable,
-- or a default string in case
-- the variable is not found
function getUsername()
    return os.getenv("USERNAME") or "Oh no!"
end

-- let's do a simple comparison
-- and print the test result
function checkUsername(username)
    if username == getUsername() then
        tex.print("Authenticated.")
    else
        tex.print("I'm calling the \\TeX\\ police.")
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\authenticate[1]{\luadirect{checkUsername(\luastring{#1})}}

\begin{document}

Trying with \verb|paulo|: \authenticate{paulo}

Trying with \verb|david|: \authenticate{david}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Call teh cops]

Comment: -1 for offence to my good name!!!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: ♥

Comment: now that _is_ scary.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: LOL `:)`

Answer (score 6):

This needs

```
pdflatex --shell-escape
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
{\everyeof{\noexpand}
\xdef\usrtest{\@@input"|echo \string$USER""\expandafter}}
\makeatother

\def\me{davidc}

\begin{document}

\ifx\me\usrtest ME \else IMPOSTER\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: And Unix! You'd need `echo %USERNAME%` on Windows (Of course, the question does say `$USER).

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the pipe syntax for `\input` is not supported by the 'release' version of XeTeX, although that will I think change.

Comment: @JosephWright The support of "pipe" inputs in XeTeX has been announced for the next version (currently under testing) by Khaled Hosny.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know, hence the comment. Even once it's released it may be some time before people update their XeTeX though (the shaper change may put people off until a lot of testing is done).

Answer (score 0):

As I've said, I don't think you can access the username directly (Edit: OK, so you can, see above), but the `optional` package should work nicely:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[bob]{optional}    %\usepackage[joe]{optional}

\begin{document}
    This document was compiled by \opt{joe}{Joe Schmoe}\opt{bob}{Bob Wilbur}!
\end{document}
```